# Construct queries with a condition

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j, neo4j-apoc

I am using Spring Data [Neo4j](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neo4j) and I have a repository like this:

```java
public interface MyNeo4jRepository extends Neo4jRepository<Object, Long> {

    @Query("with ['X', 'Y','Z'] as list_labels, "
            + "$appsFilter as appsList\n "
            + "MATCH (apps:) where apps.n IN appsList "
            + "MATCH (a)<-[:event]-(nodes) "
            + "WHERE any(x IN labels(nodes) WHERE x IN list_labels) "
            + "CALL apoc.path.expandConfig(nodes, { "
            + "relationshipFilter: 'R1|R2>',"
            + "labelFilter: '-l1|>l2',"
            + "maxLevel: 6,"
            + "endNodes: [apps],"
            + "uniqueness: 'NODE_PATH'}) YIELD path "
            + "unwind nodes(path) as n  "
           ...
}
```

I want to create this query using conditions like this:

```java
@Query("with ['X', 'Y','Z'] as list_labels, "
            + "$appsFilter as appsList\n "
            + "MATCH (apps:) where apps.n IN appsList "
            + "MATCH (a)<-[:event]-(nodes) "
            + "WHERE any(x IN labels(nodes) WHERE x IN list_labels) "
           if (condition) + "WHERE  ...." else + ""
            + "CALL apoc.path.expandConfig(nodes, { "
  ...
```

Is there a way to do it in the Neo4j query or do I have to do it with Spring composable repositories?

Comment: What language is the sample code in? Java? It doesn't seem to be [Cypher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cypher_(query_language)).

Comment: yes java with spring data neo4j, the query is in cypher

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is the `CASE` construct

```
'WHERE  ....'
+
CASE 
    WHEN condition1 THEN  'cypherFragement1'
    WHEN condition2 THEN  'cypherFragement2'
    ELSE 'cypherFragementElse'
END
+
.....
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can rewrite your entire cypher via apoc.do.when or apoc.do.case functions, which provide conditional judgment.